# Binding objects to controls on JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, jstl

I have the following class that I'm using in my Java with JSP applicaton.

// 
public class QuestionBO implements Serializable{

```
private int questionId;
private int testID;
private String question;

private TutorBO infoAboutTutor;
private SubjectBO infoAboutSubject;
private TestBO infoAboutTest;
private List<AnswerBO> answers;

public QuestionBO() {
}

public QuestionBO(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
```

getter & setter....

The JSP page has a form where each Question (its String representation) has a checkbox next to it. A user marks some of the questions and submits the form to the server for processing by a servlet.

What is the conventional way of binding the Question objects with the checkboxes so that I could find out what Questions have been selected?

Currently I'm using the following approach for constructing the form:

//

```
    <c:if test="${not empty questionsForSubject}">
    <form  action="/TutorWebApp/controller" method="POST" name="addQuestionForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add_question_list" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testName" value="${testName}"/>            
        <table border ="1">
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${questionsForSubject}" var="question">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name ="choosen_question" 
                                   value="${question.getQuestion()}">
                            ${question.getQuestion()}
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Add questions "/>              
    </form>
```

And I shouldn't use frameworks.

Thanks

And I have last question

```
    <c:if test="${not empty questionsForSubject}">
    <form  action="/TutorWebApp/controller" method="POST" name="addQuestionForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add_question_list" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testName" value="${testName}"/> 
        <input type="hidden" name="questionsForSubject" value="${questionsForSubject}"/>
        <table border ="1">
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${questionsForSubject.keySet()}" var="questionID">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name ="choosen_question" value="${questionID}">
                            ${questionsForSubject.get(questionID).getQuestion()}
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить вопросы"/>              
    </form>
```

How I can get map from this page on servlet?

Comment: I have previous page where I choose subject from combobox for that I show list of questions in next page

Comment: Set<QuestionBO> questionsForSubject = 
`code`                  AddTestLogic.getListOfQuestionsBySubject(subjectIdByName);            
            request.setAttribute("questionsForSubject", questionsForSubject);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each checkbox an unique value. For example, the unique question identifier:

```html
<c:forEach items="${questionsForSubject}" var="question">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chosen_question" value="${question.questionId}" />
            ${question.question}
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This way you'll be able to grab all checked values by just the following call in the servlet:

```
String[] chosenQuestions = request.getParameterValues("chosen_question");
```

Comment: @Andrey: I think because it's rather clumsy to collect the selected values in the servlet side if you put the value in the name instead. You'd need to introduce a loop over parameter names/map and perform some null/empty checks, which is after all unnecessary if you just set the value as input value the normal way.

Comment: @BalusC I agree with you. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an unique name for each `checkbox` as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="${question.questionId}" />
```

or:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choosen_question_${question.questionId}" />
```

After that, you're already able to identify each `checkbox` in your *servlet*

Comment: guiestionId is id from db. I can't show or use this value on jsp

Comment: @user712183 Why not? So create a map of IDs to a page-level ID, and keep it across submits. You have to have a way of uniquely identifying a question--either by index or an ID, whether or not it's the DB id.

Comment: The same can be said about the field `question` in your class QuestionBO. Why you have a field `questionId` in the class if you don't use it? At the query of the field `question` to database and also get the value of `questionId`

Comment: @Dave Newton Can you explain me, please, as I can autogenerated id in jsp and as I can get map with Map<AutogenKey, QuestionBO>. And I can get on controller with help request just String or String[]

Comment: Access the DB from JSP is the bad practice. Show how you get `question` in class QuestionBO. The field `questionId` should be got the same manner.

Comment: @Andrey Kapelchik I cannot use access to DB on jsp. I have dao-classes, dto-classes and bo-classes and initialize fields in bo-class with help mapper-classes with methods toBO, toDTO

Comment: Show me how you get `question` from class QuestionBO. It's a code of your DAO.

Comment: -1 it's rather clumsy to collect the selected values in the servlet side if you put the value in the name instead. You'd need to introduce a loop over parameter names/map and perform some null/empty checks, which is after all unnecessary if you just set the value as input value the normal way.